# Login/Consume Api rest with Spring Security basic Auth not Working

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm new to spring security so for learning purpouses I created a api using `spring-boot 2.0.3.RELEASE` and `spring-boot-starter-security`.

Here is what I got

```
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {       
auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("USER");
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

    }
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/security")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    SpringSecurityService service;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Person findOne(@PathVariable("id") final int id) {
        return service.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

When I try to consume the get method `findOne` via some browser a Login form is promped since all browsers support basic auth I try to login using `admin` as user and password but an error from wrong credentials is shown.

I tried also to consume the mehod via postman sending Authorization and `$2a$10$c6MFPW.7MD7a.2V2rJYlXO0.YOLQEmsbu5GBmFsf.jShduBPenQ6O` as the value.

I got the value for the password from here:

```
System.out.println(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode("admin"));
```

I know this is some rookie mistake but I dont know what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code out in my own project. It would appear you're just missing an `@Configuration` annotation on your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` thus the default configuration is taking place. Where the `user` name, and the logged password in the console would work.

Working example - https://github.com/DarrenForsythe/sof-60178305